# Animating WordPress (Twenty Thirteen) sub-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate

I'm trying to add an animation to the dropdown menu of wordpress. I'm using this code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("ul#menu-menu-1").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
            .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "show", "opacity": "show" }, 200 );
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu')
            .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "hide", "opacity": "hide" }, 200 );
    });

});
```

But 1) it goes ON an already "in position" sub-menu and 2) the sub-menu of the first parent is instead the sub-menu of the second one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is of the entire navigation menu, causing all of the sub-menus to appear when the mouse hovers over any part of the menu.

Try using `jQuery("ul#menu-menu-1 li").hover(function() {` which will select the individual `li` elements within the menu instead.

Then use `.children` instead of `.find`, as to target `li` elements that are direct children of the menu item being hovered upon.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("ul#menu-menu-1 li").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul.sub-menu')
            .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "show", "opacity": "show" }, 200 );
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).children('ul.sub-menu')
            .stop(true, true).delay(50).animate({ "height": "hide", "opacity": "hide" }, 200 );
    });
});
```

For the animation to appear, remove the following from your `styles.css near line 906`

```
ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul, .nav-menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your code is live on the link above but the animation doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I've included a CSS edit to make the animation appear.  It's not showing because your CSS is forcing a `display: block` on the sub-menu, canceling out the animation.